# Array: I want a function that print array in not consecutive order

Tags: php, laravel

I have a function that returns an array, the array if full of values like 'up' and 'down'. what i want to print  values where the two consecutive values are not the same. example: if the first value is up, and the second values also up, it should print only the first one, likewise for down. it should keep on printing if the consecutive are different.  thus the output is expected to be up, down, up, down ?

```
$a_ret = [];    

            foreach ($o_response as $o_status) {                
                    $a_ret[] = [
                        'value' => $o_status->values,
                        'timestamp' => $o_status->created_at
                    ];
        }

        return $a_ret;

    }
```

Comment: You could remember the latest value and check if the current value isn't the same as the last value. `$last = $o_status->values`

Comment: how about the values between?

Comment: does your array contains same number of elements having "up" and "down",.. if no then how would you like to display if one of them displayed completely

Comment: @abrahamfoto The value that contains up and down is $o_status->values, right?

Comment: yes, you are right. it is.

Comment: @abrahamfoto Check my answer to see what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will put every last value you put in your return array in the `$last` variable. So `down, up, up up, down, up, up, down` will become `down, up, down, up, down`.

```
$a_ret = [];    

$last = null;
foreach ($o_response as $o_status) {
    if($last != $o_status->values) {
        $a_ret[] = [
            'value' => $o_status->values,
            'timestamp' => $o_status->created_at
        ];
        $last = $o_status->values;
    } else {
        // Add this else if you want up, up, up to become up, up.
        // See  kapil.dev  comment on this answer
        $last = null;
    }
}

return $a_ret;
```

Comment: we are losing data in this case

Comment: What do you mean? He only wants not consecutive values, that means you will lose consecutive data.

Comment: if there are 2 consecutive same values, this will skip next one, if 3 consecutive  same values , it will skip 2. Thats what I meant in losing data

Comment: Isn't that what OP wants?

Comment: dont know, I am assuming to retain all the values and return array with consecutive different values

Comment: Changed my answer to fix your problem (if OP wants this)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129545/discussion-between-kapil-dev-and-bart-bergmans).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it like this:

```
$a = ['up', 'up', 'down', 'up', 'down', 'down'];

$arr = [];
foreach($a as $el) {
    if(!empty($arr)) {
        if(end($arr) != $el)
            $arr[] = $el;
    } else {
        $arr[] = $el;
    }
}

print_r($arr);

// Output: ['up', 'down', 'up', 'down']
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: we are losing data in this case

Comment: But the question doesn't said about the losing of data?

Comment: @kapil.dev you are absolutely right, we are losing lots of data. the main project is about web monitoring tool. i want to have this tool a table or statistics, when it is 'up', or 'down'. when a website is checked every 10 minutes and it was down for days, thus  it is not important data to have lots of down values. just by looking at the 'up' and 'down' values ' you can simply tell  how long it was down. short and clear data. Sorry, I am not good in english, but i hope it answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one

```
$a = ['up', 'up', 'down', 'up', 'down', 'down'];`

foreach($a as $value) {
    if($value != next($a)){
      echo $value;
    }
}
```